# HA Proxy Configuration with MariaDB Galera cluster

Tags: mariadb, galera

I have a 3 node MariaDB Galera Cluster (MDB-001,MDB-002,MDB-003) with HA Proxy and two databases (DB1,DB2)

I am connecting to MariaDB Galera Cluster through HA Proxy and HA Proxy configured to route connections to least loaded node.

Now I need such a configuration that Transactions on DB1 should go to MDB-001 and Transactions on DB2 should go to MDB-002.
In the event of MDB-001 down then connection of DB1 should be routed to least connections node and similarly when MDB-002 down then 
connection of DB2 should be routed to least connection node.

Could you please help me to for setting such configuration.

Comment: I question whether there is any advantage to explicitly directing traffic like that.  Just let any transaction go to any node.  Galera is happy with that.

Comment: I am trying to write to a database should be done on only one node to avoid dead lock.

Comment: That won't solve it.  It is still possible to get deadlocks even with all writes going to a single node.  You have to be ready to handle deadlocks.

Comment: In case of update of the same record on different nodes,first committed transaction will be permanent to the database and other transaction will get dead lock error.
However if same record is getting updated from multiple connection on the same node then first transaction will lock the record and other connections wait for 50 seconds(default value of innodb_lock_wait_timeout) then error out with message Lock wait timeout exceeded.

Therefore by setting innodb_lock_wait_timeout as per my application needs,I would like to route all writes of a database to only one node.

Comment: Unless you are doing hundreds of transactions per second, or spending long amounts of time between `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`, you probably won't get a deadlock or lock_wait more often than once an hour.  I claim (feel free to prove me wrong) that you are trying to optimize something that is too rare to worry about.

Comment: You are very much correct.I dont want any of my transaction should fail for dead lock and re-initiate that transaction again.

Comment: Minimizing deadlocks is a practical goal.  Totally eliminating them may be impossible.

Comment: Totally agree with you.